# Is equality $\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}-x) = -\cos(x)$ always true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$\sin(\frac{3\pi}{2}-x) = -\cos(x)$

Is above equality always true even if $x \gt \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: If it is true for $x<\pi/2$, why would it be false for other values ?

Comment: Because I wasn't sure if it is always sin(...) = -cos(...) or maybe sometimes it is sin(...) = cos(...). But now I get it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, you don't need to harass op for asking questions that you may think is obvious.

Comment: @abel: no harassment at all, this was the precise point on which the OP needed some help.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, the same information can also be gotten by asking the question in a different way e.g, why does the op think it is true? you get more out of that than your question. of course, this is how i see it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By the [addition formula for $\sin$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities),
$$
\begin{align}
\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}2 - x\right) &= \sin\left(\frac{\pi}2 + \pi-x\right) = \overbrace{\sin(\pi/2)}^{=1}\cos(\pi-x)+\sin(\pi-x)\overbrace{\cos(\pi/2)}^{=0}\\
&=\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos(x).
\end{align}
$$

So yes, it is always true.

Comment: why not $\sin(\frac{3\pi} 2 - x) = \sin (\frac{3\pi} 2)\cos x -\cos(\frac{3\pi} 2) \sin x = -\cos x?$

Comment: Sure, just as good. You can show it in arbitrarily many ways. @abel

Answer (score 6):

By the antisupplement formula, $\sin(x+\pi)=-\sin(x)$, hence

$$\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}2-x\right)=-\sin(\frac\pi2-x).$$

Now, the complement formula
$$\sin\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)=\cos(x)$$is well known and has no restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

why not $$\sin\left(\frac{3\pi} 2 - x\right) = \sin \left(\frac{3\pi} 2\right)\cos x -\cos\left(\frac{3\pi} 2\right) \sin x = -\cos x?$$